# How can I specialise a destructor for just one case, or some cases?

Tags: c++, templates, destructor, template-specialization

I can specialise a destructor for one case, but I'm having trouble telling the compiler to just use a normal destructor for any other cases:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int = 0>
struct Foo
{
    ~Foo();
};

int main()
{
    {
        Foo<> a; // Normal destructor called
    }

    {
        Foo<7> a; // Special destructor called
    }

}

template<>
Foo<7>::~Foo() { std::cout << "Special Foo"; }

template<>
Foo<>::~Foo() {}    // Normal destructor does nothing.
```

This works fine, but now if I add another template argument, for example Foo<3> a; then the linker says that it can't find the destructor definition. How can I just say I want a special destructor just for number 7, and handle any other cases with a normal destructor?

I tried:

```
Foo::~Foo() {} // Argument list missing

Foo<int>::~Foo() {} // Illegal type for non-type template parameter

template<>
Foo<int>::~Foo() {} // Same thing

template<int>
Foo<>::~Foo() {} // Function template has already been defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I just say I want a special destructor just for number 7, and handle any other cases with a normal destructor?

The general destructor should be defined as:

```
template <int I>
Foo<I>::~Foo() { std::cout << "general dtor"; }
```

For

```
template<>
Foo<>::~Foo() {}    // Normal destructor does nothing.
```

Because the template parameter has a default value `0`, so the above code is just a specialization of `Foo<0>`, just like what you did for `Foo<7>`. It's equivalent with

```
template<>
Foo<0>::~Foo() {}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/z5dnxVUflmGzeyS7)

Comment: Very very sweet, thanks. Can they be defined inline in the class itself like normal/untemplated class functions?

Comment: I've already accepted your answer, but I'm having trouble defining it in the class itself like you said you could. If it's not too much trouble could you just give a quick snippet of one definition in the Foo struct inline? The code's already set up in the LIVE link you gave.